# Can't get a child page to put markers on a map in opener page

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm at wits end.

I have a Page A containing a map (the Map object, named 'map', has global scope), plus a button which opens a child Page B. Page B, in turn, has a button which should place a marker on the map on Page A. Links to the pages in question, and a synopsis, follow:

Page A: http://friendsofhillforest.org/maps/HillForestTrailmap-v2-2-topo.html The 'Manage My Markers' button opens Page B in a new window

Page B: http://friendsofhillforest.org/maps/tools/marker_mgmt2.html

When the page B button 'Map Selected' attempts to place a marker on the map of Page A, I get the error 'Error: Invalid value for property : [object Object] (main.js:1)'

Here's a synopsis of my code so you don't have to wade through these large scripts:

Page A:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" name="location" value="Manage My Markers" title="Manage My Markers" onClick="launchMarkerManager();">
    ...
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
        ...
        function launchMarkerManager() {
            var newwindow = window.open('http://friendsofhillforest.org/maps/tools/marker_mgmt1.html','Hill Forest Marker Management Tool', document.height - 50, document.width - 50); newwindow.focus();
        }
        ...
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            ...
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Page B:

```
<body>
    ...
    <input type="button" id="mapchecks" value="Map Selected" onclick="mapChecks(); />
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
        function mapChecks() {
            //add the markers in the results list to the calling map window
            var map = window.opener.map;
            var markerFile = '../icons/numbermarkers/iconr25.png';
            var thisMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                ...     
            });
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(36.5,-74.1));
        }
        ...
    </script>
</body>
```

I've done a lot of googling and a lot of searching Stack Overflow, but I don't seem to be able to find another example of this problem. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you get any other error shown in the console other than `Invalid value for property : [object Object] (main.js:1)'` ? Because identifying error in main.js is merely not possible.

Comment: BTW chrome console or firebug?

Comment: Links don't work. (Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): The server could not be found.)

Comment: Nope, no errors other than the one I've listed. I'm using Safari's error console, but I also see the error in FF. The links are working for me. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I also get a "404 Error File Not Found" on both the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly what the problem is, but it must be caused by the two different documents.

It works for me when I transfer the mapChecks-function(with some modifications, e.g. removing the 1st line) into page A and call `opener.mapChecks()` in page B

Comment: Thanks, that works and it's a nice work-around; I should have thought of it...a fresh pair of eyes always helps. It's still troubling though, not understanding why it doesn't work when the same function is on a child page, since it leaves me not sure whether the problem is my coding or, instead, some Google Maps API bug I should report. I'd vote you up but I'm a newb here and don't have enough reputation points.